# Scope of nls selfStart functions

Tags: r, nls

I'm building a package that will:

1. read in a data set
2. determine which components are needed to model the data<sup>1</sup>
3. build a self-starting NLS model using those components
4. apply that model to the data

The result is stored in a list that contains the data, model, and nls result. Everything works until step 4. I've stored my constructed models in the list, and R no longer recognizes them as selfStart functions.

Here's a toy example illustrating my problem. The following function (from the `SSlogis` manual) works fine at top-level:

```R
 Chick.1 <- ChickWeight[ChickWeight$Chick == 1, ]
 fm1 <- nls(weight ~ SSlogis(Time, Asym, xmid, scal), data = Chick.1)
 fm1
```

> Nonlinear regression model
>     model: weight ~ SSlogis(Time, Asym, xmid, scal)
>      data: Chick.1
>     Asym   xmid   scal
>   937.02  35.22  11.41
>    residual sum-of-squares: 76.66
>
> Number of iterations to convergence: 0
>   Achieved convergence tolerance: 7.778e-07

But when I store the function and data together in a list, R doesn't see the selfstarting function as selfstarting anymore:

```R
myobj <- list()
myobj$model <- SSlogis
myobj$data <- ChickWeight[ChickWeight$Chick == 1, ]

nls(weight ~ myobj$model(Time, Asym, xmid, scal), data = myobj$data)
```

> Error in getInitial.default(func, data, mCall = as.list(match.call(func,  :
>     no 'getInitial' method found for "function" objects

My workflow will eventually include processing dozens of datasets, so I'd like to keep each dataset and its associated model in its own object (and these objects will probably end up in a list of objects). Is there some way to maintain or restore the environment of my selfStart functions even after they're stored inside another list?

## UPDATE

In response to Gregor's suggestion, I tried this:

```
nls(as.formula(sprintf("weight ~ %s(Time, Asym, xmid, scal)",
                       "myobj$model")), data = myobj$data)
```

> Error in nls(as.formula(sprintf("weight ~ %s(Time, Asym, xmid, scal)",  :
>     singular gradient
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In nls(as.formula(sprintf("weight ~ %s(Time, Asym, xmid, scal)",  :
>     No starting values specified for some parameters.
>   Initializing ‘Asym’, ‘xmid’, ‘scal’ to '1.'.
>   Consider specifying 'start' or using a selfStart model

## Update 2

Inspired by @Gregor I came up with a workaround:

```
nlsDispatch <- function(obj){
  GLOBAL_NLS <<- obj$model
  nls(weight ~ GLOBAL_NLS(Time, Asym, xmid, scal), data = myobj$data) 
}

nlsDispatch(myobj)
```

> Nonlinear regression model
>     model: weight ~ GLOBAL_NLS(Time, Asym, xmid, scal)
>      data: myobj$data
>     Asym   xmid   scal
>   937.02  35.22  11.41
>    residual sum-of-squares: 76.66
>
> Number of iterations to convergence: 0
>   Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.621e-07

That works, but dropping my function into the global environment is ugly. And it suggests that if I had a better handle on environments I should be able to avoid abusing the global environment to get this done.

<sup>1</sup>: In my application, this is *mostly* a matter of counting peaks, and figuring out how many Normal curves are needed to model them.

Comment: Your're treating the right-hand side of a formula as if it's an argument... but it's not. There may be a better way, but I would suggest constructing your formula as a string `sprintf("weight ~ %s(Time, Asym, xmid, scal)", "SSlogis")` and then using `as.formula()` on it.

Comment: @Gregor thanks - I tried that, and got a slightly different error. Note that I used "myobj$model" instead of "SSlogis". `SSlogis` works as-is already.

Comment: I would think my version would work like this: `sprintf("weight ~ %s(Time, Asym, xmid, scal)", myobj$model)` if `myobj$model` has a string name of the function rather than the actual function object.

Comment: @Gregor That works for my example. But for the package, I'm not going to be using pre-built models like SSlogis, I'm generating new models for each dataset. I was hoping to store each data set along with its model in an object. This will be convenient when looping over dozens of files in a directory. But maybe that's more work than building on your suggestion, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** This works:

```
Model <- myobj$model
nls(weight ~ Model(Time, Asym, xmid, scal), data = myobj$data)
```

giving

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: weight ~ Model(Time, Asym, xmid, scal)
   data: myobj$data
  Asym   xmid   scal 
937.02  35.22  11.41 
 residual sum-of-squares: 76.66

Number of iterations to convergence: 0 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.621e-07
```

**2)** It does seem scoping is messed up for self starting functions. The problem appears in `getInitial.formula` which uses this line:

```
func <- get(as.character(object[[2L]][[1L]]))
```

Note that there is no second argument to `get` (the environment) so it does not pay attention to environments.

Thus if you want to put the solution above in a function then it you will need to work around it like this:

```
f <- function() {
  myobj <- list()
  myobj$model <- SSlogis
  myobj$data <- ChickWeight[ChickWeight$Chick == 1, ]
  Model <<- myobj$model
  nls(weight ~ Model(Time, Asym, xmid, scal), data = myobj$data)
}
f()
```

**3)** Another workaound is to attach Model.  That would keep it out of the global workspace.  Note that we detach it afterwards so the function does not leave any trace.

```
f2 <- function() {
  on.exit(detach())
  if (any(grepl("list", search()))) stop("list already on search path")
  myobj <- list()
  myobj$model <- SSlogis
  myobj$data <- ChickWeight[ChickWeight$Chick == 1, ]
  attach(list(Model = myobj$model))
  nls(weight ~ Model(Time, Asym, xmid, scal), data = myobj$data)
}
f2()
```

Note that if the `detach` does not occur then the next time an `attach` is done there would be two items attached on the search list (whereas in the prior approach it always overwrites the global variable so that can't happen) so we check that there is no such list on the search path and stop with an error if there is.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Point taken. May be worth adding a step to confirm that the parameters estimated in the nls result match those in the model. If anything goes wrong with the attach/detach, it's quite likely this will still 'work' with an incorrect model.

Comment: Have added a check in (3).